# regex to remove ANY number/letter combination?

Tags: python, regex

It's easy to remove all digits from the following `string`:

```
>>> string = "asprx12303 hello my 321 name is Tom 2323dsad843, 657a b879 843aa943 aa... 2ci 2ci"
>>> modified = re.sub(r'\d+', '', string)
>>> print(modified)
'asprx hello my  name is Tom dsad, a b aa aa... ci ci'
```

But I want to remove every standalone digit (e.g. `321` by itself) and every combination of letters and numbers in the string (e.g. `843aa943` and `asprx12303`).

This is what I have so far:

```
>>> modified2 = re.sub(r'\w+\d+', '', string)
>>> print(modified2)
' hello my  name is Tom , a   aa... 2ci 2ci'
```

So, these two patterns work pretty well, but I'm left with `2ci` at the end. How can I make an all-encompassing regex for this issue? My solution is ok so far, but is not quite what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
r'\w*[0-9]\w*'
```

That should match any contiguous run of word characters containing at least one digit.